# gRPC: Add properties to context from decorator or ServiceInterceptor

Tags: python, grpc

I'm using decorators for authentication. If that succeeds I want to extend the `context` with additional information. How can this be achieved?

```
@require_authorization
def test(request, context):
    <...>

def require_authorization(func):
    def wrapper(request, context):
        <...How can I extend the context here?...>
        return func(request, context)
    return wrapper
```

I have also tried the ServiceInterceptor, but got stuck that route as well:

```
class Interceptor(grpc.ServerInterceptor):

    def intercept_service(self, continuation, handler_call_details):
        <...Can I extend the metadata here somehow?...>
        return continuation(handler_call_details)

server = grpc.server(
            futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10),
            interceptors=(Interceptor(),),
            )
```

**Workaround with a decorator**

Based on Lidi Zheng's reply (thanks!) I am using the following decorator. Probably the most annoying aspect is having to provide implementations for all the methods of the abstract base class. Since this is poorly documented I got them from the source.

```py
class AuthServicerContext(grpc.ServicerContext):

    def __init__(self, context: grpc.ServicerContext, func_name):
        self._original_context = context
        meta = dict(context.invocation_metadata())

    def abort(self, code, details):
        self._original_context.abort(code, details)

    def abort_with_status(self, status):
        self._original_context.abort_with_status(status)

    def add_callback(self, callback):
        self._original_context.add_callback(callback)

    def auth_context(self):
        self._original_context.auth_context()

    def cancel(self):
        self._original_context.cancel()

    def invocation_metadata(self):
        self._original_context.invocation_metadata()

    def is_active(self):
        self._original_context.is_active()

    def peer(self):
        self._original_context.peer()

    def peer_identities(self):
        self._original_context.peer_identities()

    def peer_identity_key(self):
        self._original_context.peer_identity_key()

    def send_initial_metadata(self, initial_metadata):
        self._original_context.send_initial_metadata(initial_metadata)

    def set_code(self,code):
        self._original_context.set_code(code)

    def set_details(self, details):
        self._original_context.set_details(details)

    def set_trailing_metadata(self, trailing_metadata):
        self._original_context.abort(trailing_metadata)

    def time_remaining(self):
        self._original_context.time_remaining()

def require_authorization(func):
    def wrapper(self, request, context):
        return func(self, request, AuthServicerContext(context, func.__name__))
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, adding properties to the `ServicerContext` through interceptor is not supported. See the [history](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L13-python-interceptors.md) of the server-side interceptor.

On the other hand, using the decorators for authentication is possible:

```
class MyPowerfulServicerContext(grpc.ServicerContext):
    def __init__(self, original_context: grpc.ServicerContext):
        self._original_context = original_context
        ...Perform authentication with metadata / peer identity / etc.

    def ...Your_extended_functions

    # You can port the invocation  of methods to the original context
    def abort(self, code, details):
        self._original_context.abort(code, details)

    ...



def require_authorization(func):
    def wrapper(request, context):
        return func(request, MyPowerfulServicerContext(context))
    return wrapper
```

Hope this is helpful for your use case, if I miss understood, please left a comment. Also, feel free to file issues to https://github.com/grpc/grpc.

Comment: Pity. I was already using decorators, but yours is actually more elegant, so thanks!

Comment: Although this decorator enables me to check stuff before a function gets called, I wouldn't know how to use it to extend the context and pass additional information to the function. Any idea?

Comment: To help you more effectively, you might need to explain your use case in more details. e.g. What kinds of information, and add to context object by what means?

Comment: Thanks, I got the workaround based on your suggestion working and added that to the question. Still

Comment: Some time on, and still… https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24470