# asyncio gRPC: Add properties to context from decorator or server interceptor

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, grpc, grpc-python

I'm trying to compute inforamtion from invocation_metadata and pass it to the func to avoid computing it again in the function. This worked with gRPC but when we implemented asyncio this doesn't work anymore.

```
def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(self, request, context):
        #get info from invocation_metadata
        metadata = dict(context.invocation_metadata())
        # compute something based on the invocation metadata
        context.pass_to_func = "computed value"
        return await func(self, request, context)
    return wrapper
```

Error: "Unexpected <class 'AttributeError'>: 'grpc._cython.cygrpc._ServicerContext' object has no attribute 'pass_to_func '"

```
context['pass_to_func'] = "computed value"
```

Error: "Unexpected <class 'TypeError'>: 'grpc._cython.cygrpc._ServicerContext' object does not support item assignment"

Before we implemented asyncio gRPC, assing properties as discussed in the below links work.
With async wrapper and 'grpc._cython.cygrpc._ServicerContext I am looking to add properties before passing it to the function

[gRPC: Add properties to context from decorator or ServiceInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584032/grpc-add-properties-to-context-from-decorator-or-serviceinterceptor)

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24470